# I am using sybase ase database .There is no function of last then how to fetch last 10 record in sybase?

Tags: sybase

I am using sybase ase database .There is no function of  last  then how to fetch last 10 record in sybase ?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score -2):

We know that in sybase ase there is no last function  then alternate solution is

create another temporary table with additional identity column  as

create table #mnp (srno int identity ,id int ,name varchar(10),salary int)
then
insert into  #mnp
select * from Emp

now find last 10 records as
select top 10 * from #mnp order by srno desc.

Comment: There's no `order by` in the `insert/select`, so no guarantee of the order of records inserted into #mnp; the `insert/select` is generating sequential/identify values for a randomly sorted data set; net result: final `select` is basically picking 10 random rows from Emp ... no need to jump through all these hoops ... save time and ASE resources with `select top 10 * from Emp` [I'm guessing this really isn't what you want hence importance of previous comment about providing sample data, expected output]

Comment: select top 10 * from Emp  Top is used only fetch top records .But if there is requirement of fetching last 10 records then use it alternately .If you have any other method then please tell us  how to fetch last 10 record in sybase ASE .